# Scaffolding Identity in .NET6.0 generates lots of Deference NULL warnings

Tags: .net-6.0, identity

After performing a Scaffolding update on a .NET6.0 Web application, all of the Identity functions are generating this type of warning messages.

```
Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Logout.cshtml(10,13,10,26): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

I am able to hide the warning by adding  " #nullable disable " below the using statements; however, I was wondering if this is even normal since this is Generated Code from Microsoft.
Is there a future update that will take care of these warnings out of the box or should I just continue to hide the warnings from the Identity objects?

Comment: same here, getting a bunch of "CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type."